# Remove query param from URL on button click not working

Tags: javascript, query-string

I want to remove a query param in the URL on button click so the link will be amended from `www.example.com/?queryparam=hello` to `www.example.com/`.

When I try:

```
window.location.href.split('?')[0];
```

In the console, it returns the href minus the query param (correctly). But in actual browser test it doesn't execute the code on the actual button click.

Here is my code:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('?queryParam=') > -1) {
    $('.button').click(function() {
      window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    });
  }
  return;
}, false);
```

Comment: are you trying to redirect the page to the one without query params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting and accessing the array doesn't mutate the original string. The reason you saw it in the console as the base URL is because it evaluates to `www.example.com` but you aren't changing the original `window.location.href`. Reassign it:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
```

Your code:

```
window.location.href.split('?')[0];
```

Is just an expression. It evaluates to a value, it essentially has no effects. Reassigning will change the location as expected. Note that `window` is not needed (unless you have a local variable named `location`). You could also shorten it to:

```
location = location.href.split('?')[0];
```

Or even:

```
location.assign(location.href.split('?')[0]);
```